# Can I bring a used robotic vacuum cleaner to India from France? Note: I am not returning on a permanent basis.What are the custom rules around that?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, france

What are Customs rules regarding bringing vacuum cleaner from abroad to India ?

Comment: Custom rules are often based on value, how much is your used machine worth?

Comment: It was bought at a discounted price of just 60 euros whereas the actual price was 110 euros. @Willeke